# CosmoDB query group by where count more than 1 get the first record

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to query the first record of each group sorted by a date and partitioned by an id, and I just need records that have duplicate id.

This is the sample data

```
{"s_id": "123", "my_date": "2022-10-12", "a_value": 1 },
{"s_id": "123", "my_date": "2022-11-12", "a_value": 22},
{"s_id": "123", "my_date": "2022-11-13", "a_value": 23}, // should be in the output
{"s_id": "125", "my_date": "2022-10-20", "a_value": 2},
{"s_id": "125", "my_date": "2022-10-23", "a_value": 4},  // should be in the output
{"s_id": "241", "my_date": "2022-11-01", "a_value": 12},  
{"s_id": "242", "my_date": "2022-11-02", "a_value": 11}
```

So, the output should only contain the row 3 and 5 since there are multiple records with s_id 123 and 125. The last 2 rows should not be in the output since there is no duplicate s_id for them.

Expected result

```
{"s_id": "123", "my_date": "2022-11-13", "a_value": 23},  
{"s_id": "125", "my_date": "2022-10-23", "a_value": 4}
```

I tried doing the following but I am getting the wrong the a_value since it's part of the group by

```
    SELECT d.s_id, 
           d.my_date, 
           d.source, 
           d.a_value 
      FROM (SELECT c.s_id, 
             MAX(c.my_date) AS my_date, 
             MAX(c.a_value) AS a_value, 
             COUNT(1) AS cnt
             FROM c GROUP BY c.s_id) d
     WHERE d.cnt > 1
```

The problem I am getting above is the a_value is incorrect with the MAX. Also, I searched and there is no way to do a join in cosmo on the same container.

Any helps are welcome, thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the `EXISTS` operator with correlated subquery as the following:

```
SELECT s_id, my_date, a_value
FROM table_name T
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM table_name D
    WHERE D.s_id = T.s_id AND D.a_value > T.a_value
  )
AND EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM table_name D
    WHERE D.s_id = T.s_id AND D.a_value <> T.a_value
  )
```

The first `NOT EXISTS` is to select only rows with maximum 'a_value', and the second `EXISTS` is to ensure that there is more than one row with the same s_id and different a_value.

Comment: Hi @ahmed, I believe this is a SQL query, CosmoDb doesn't work this way

Comment: Yes, it's a SQL query, but before I posted this answer I checked that cosmoDb supports Exists operator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/subquery